# Missing required key: but not sure how to find it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have just installed elasticsearch and everything is coming up correctly. But in order to make my search results a link, I need to pass a movie_id through the SearchController.(the error message is missing required keys: [:movie_id]) I have tried many different things, but no luck.

**search_controller.rb**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
  if params[:q].nil?
    @movie_genres = []
  else
    @movie_genres = MovieGenre.where(movie_id: @movie).search params[:q]
  end
end

end
```

**search.html.erb**

```
<% @movie_genres.each do |movie_genre| %>
<%= link_to movie_genre.title, movie_movie_genres_path(@movie) %>
    <% end %>
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can we see your stack trace ?

Comment: here is the stack trace: app/controllers/search_controller.rb:9:in `search'

Comment: This is a single trace, and it points to line 9 which is empty in the code you gave us. Maybe in your view @movie is nil ?

Comment: Maybe just query for "_id" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

**controller**

```
@movie_genres = MovieGenre.search params[:q]
```

**view**

```
<%= link_to movie_genre.title, movie_movie_genres_path(movie_genre.movie_id) %>
```